# Technically headless server with VNC X11 sessions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, session-manager

I'm trying to set up a headless Ubuntu 22.04 system to start detachable user sessions using VNC. I'm not so concerned with security in this case. First, I can arrange it for VNC to only listen on localhost so you have to login via ssh and forward the VNC connection in order to connect at all. And this machine won't be able to be logged into remotely at all by untrusted users, both because the network setup prevents it, and for the aforementioned reason involving ssh.

I need the VNC session to remain persistent even if all clients disconnect. I've tried using `lightdm` with the `[VNCServer]` section in the config file. Unfortunately, the VNC server created that way exits when the last VNC client disconnects, which is not what is needed. It needs to persist until someone manually logs out of it.

My current attempt involves running `vncserver` as a `systemd` service. But this is not really the way a user session is supposed to start, and I've had no luck getting a session manager that talks to the VNC X server properly. I can get `xterm` and `twm` running, but that's a pretty awful desktop environment.

All the available desktop session managers want to start the X server themselves, and they want to start an X server, not VNC (with the exception of `lightdm` up there). None of them seem at all OK with starting with an existing X server. I suspect there's something going on there as well with their desire to create a DBUS session and talk to `systemd` and the like.

Does anybody have any good solutions for me for this problem?